# Simplify huge conditional statement

Tags: c#, optimization, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

## Abstract

There are times in life when your signals are noisy and you want to go from this

[image]

to this

[image]

There are many existing approaches that allow you to smooth data: local linear and polynomial regressions, different kinds of moving averages:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother

https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm

[https://www.stat.wisc.edu/~mchung/softwares/hk/hk.html](https://www.stat.wisc.edu/%7Emchung/softwares/hk/hk.html)

https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/smoothing_intro.html

[How to calculate a Gaussian kernel matrix efficiently in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731726/how-to-calculate-a-gaussian-kernel-matrix-efficiently-in-numpy)

[How to smooth the blocks of a 3D voxel world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351605/how-to-smooth-the-blocks-of-a-3d-voxel-world)

However I've found that for my case the best suited approach is gaussian kernel smoothing. It worked like a charm for me on a desktop but when switched to mobile device the algorithm stalled the device due to high computational requirements.

One of the reasons to that was the fact that prior to smoothing I had to equalize the sampling rate with other signal, which heavily increased the sampling rate and thus the amount of data required for processing.

This also yielded to the fact that the size of the gaussian kernel had to be tens of thousands of components which directly influenced the complexity of the algorithm for my naive approach it requires tens of thousands of elements in the filter to be multiplied and summed with tens of thousands of components from signal to receive just one component of smoothed data.

There is way to do gaussian kernel smoothing efficiently that requires the use of Fourier Transform which is very complex to implement efficiently.

So instead of going along this path I've thought that you could actually do smoothing a lot more efficiently without diving into complexities of Fourier Transforms.

Basically any signal is just a collection of pairs `[time, value]` ordered by time. When interpolated using linear interpolation it can always be represented with [Polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) and you can actually smooth one component of [Polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) (i.e. [Line Segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment)) analytically. I won't dive deeper into how you actually compute the [convolutional integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of analytically defined kernel over analytically defined line segment. It's just worth saying here that the result is a huge piecewise function:

[image]

That yields to a number of `if` statements:

```
public static Double Solution(Double x, Double w, Double x1, Double y1, Double x2, Double y2)
{
    Double result;

    if (x + w < x2 && w + x1 <= x)
    {
        result = (x * y1 - x2 * y1 - x * y2 + x1 * y2) / (x1 - x2);
    }
    else if (x1 < x + w && x < x1 && x + w < x2)
    {
        result = Math.Pow(w + x - x1, 2) * ((w + x + 2 * x1 - (3 * x2)) * y1 - (w + x - x1) * y2) * Math.Pow(w, -2) / (x1 - x2) / 6;
    }
    else if (x == x1 && x + w < x2)
    {
        result = y1 / 2 + w * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2) / 6;
    }
    else if (x + w < x2 && x1 < x && x < w + x1)
    {
        result = Math.Pow(w, -2) / (x1 - x2) * (Math.Pow(w, 3) * (y1 - y2) + 3 * w * w * (-x2 * y1 + x * (y1 - y2) + x1 * y2) - Math.Pow(x - x1, 2) * ((x + 2 * x1 - (3 * x2)) * y1 + (-x + x1) * y2) + 3 * w * (x - x1) * ((x + x1 - (2 * x2)) * y1 + (-x + x1) * y2)) / 6;
    }
    else if (x2 <= x + w && x < x1)
    {
        result = (x1 - x2) * (2 * y1 * x1 + x2 * y1 + x1 * y2 + 2 * x2 * y2 - 3 * w * (y1 + y2) - 3 * x * (y1 + y2)) * Math.Pow(w, -2) / 6;
    }
    else if (x2 <= x && w + x1 <= x && x < w + x2)
    {
        result = -Math.Pow(w - x + x2, 2) * ((w - x + x2) * y1 + (-w + x - 3 * x1 + (2 * x2)) * y2) * Math.Pow(w, -2) / (x1 - x2) / 6;
    }
    else if (x2 <= x && x < w + x1)
    {
        result = -(x1 - x2) * (2 * y1 * x1 + x2 * y1 + x1 * y2 + 2 * x2 * y2 + 3 * w * (y1 + y2) - 3 * x * (y1 + y2)) * Math.Pow(w, -2) / 6;
    }
    else if (x == x1 && (x + w == x2 && (x2 <= x && x + w < x1 && w + x2 <= x || x < w + x1) || x < w + x1 && x2 <= x + w && x < x2))
    {
        result = (-x1 + x2) * (3 * w * (y1 + y2) + (x1 - x2) * (y1 + 2 * y2)) * Math.Pow(w, -2) / 6;
    }
    else if (x < x2 && x2 <= x + w && w + x1 <= x)
    {
        result = Math.Pow(w, -2) / (x1 - x2) * (Math.Pow(w, 3) * (-y1 + y2) + 3 * w * w * (-x2 * y1 + x * (y1 - y2) + x1 * y2) + Math.Pow(x - x2, 2) * ((-x + x2) * y1 + (x - 3 * x1 + (2 * x2)) * y2) + 3 * w * (x - x2) * (-2 * x1 * y2 + x * (-y1 + y2) + x2 * (y1 + y2))) / 6;
    }
    else if (x < x2 && x2 <= x + w && x1 < x && x < w + x1)
    {
        result = Math.Pow(w, -2) / (x1 - x2) * (-2 * Math.Pow(x1, 3) * y1 + 3 * x1 * x1 * x2 * y1 + Math.Pow(x2, 3) * y1 - Math.Pow(x1, 3) * y2 - 3 * x1 * (x2 * x2) * y2 + 2 * Math.Pow(x2, 3) * y2 + 2 * Math.Pow(x, 3) * (-y1 + y2) - 3 * w * Math.Pow(x1 - x2, 2) * (y1 + y2) + 6 * x * x * (x2 * y1 - x1 * y2) + 3 * x * (2 * x1 * x2 * (-y1 + y2) + x1 * x1 * (y1 + y2) - (x2 * x2) * (y1 + y2))) / 6;
    }
    else
    {
        result = 0.0e0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And here's how it visually looks like:
[image]

You can also combine multiple line segments via sum of smoothing functions for these segments

[image]

Thus reducing the computational complexity down to number of points that you have:

## The problem

If statement above looks inefficient and there are numerical stability problems with it. When line segments defined by `x1,y1,x2,y2` are getting big numbers the result explodes. I'm trying deal with these problems but it's harder than I expected. Even careful expansion of equations introduces some strange errors in to computation. So I thought it was a good idea to consult with StackOverflow to probably get more ideas on how to optimize this statement and make it more numerically stable.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Does it need to be optimized? Sure, it's ugly to read, but I'd just add a comment saying something like "this was autogenerated with <tool here>, don't touch"

Comment: What does the calculation represent? Why do you feel the need to simplify it? Would you be better to just add comments to it (and meaningful parameter names)?

Comment: Almost certainly, you should simplify it using mathematical simplification of the current equation rather than trying to simplify the resulting code.

Comment: Guys please see updates

Comment: Did you wrote tests for it?

Comment: @Fabio this would be a question to a question ))) But no I haven't written tests for it, and more to that is that I don't have to do this because this is analytical solution generated through special mathematical software, it doesn't introduce errors... But there are edge case things that actually are ugly and wrong such as comparison of Double's

Comment: You could maybe change it to a switch/case statement, its not much cleaner but I personally find them easier to read

Comment: @Lu4, my point was, with tests you can play around with different approaches and in seconds will get a feedback is your approach correct.

Comment: Oh, now I get what you've meant, I need tests while I will be playing with this expression, good point thanks!

Comment: Can't you use the Kernel density estimation algorithms implemented by Math.NET Numerics ? https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Statistics/KernelDensity.htm#GaussianKernel

Comment: One option would be to extract each function into its own class with an IsApplicable method to check for the condition and a calculate method for the result. Put the extracted classes into a sorted list and iterate over them to get the results from the applicable functions. This way you could also test each function separately if desired.

Comment: @Gimly I'm using triangle kernel density under the hood, I've tried gaussian, rectangular, cosine, sigmoid, and many custom variants but not all of them are usable for this task. It should be noted that the kernel density function alone won't help you. It won't smooth and interpolate your signal, but this function does. You just plug your segments into it and get smooth output at any point you wish. I just need to make it more robust and numerically stable...

Comment: Why not write a service and host it? Your mobile devices could request for the "smooth" data instead of doing all the heavy work itself.

Comment: @Lennart good point, I'm using something similar to this in order to identify numerical stability problems right now

Comment: @j4rey devices can go offline at any point