# What is "Hermite Data" described in the Dual Contouring algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, mesh, voxel

I have been reading [various sources](http://www.frankpetterson.com/publications/dualcontour/dualcontour.pdf) the past hours and couldn't understand how Dual Contouring works. My problem is that I don't know the meaning of "Hermite Data" and even Google and Wikipedia couldn't help me on that. Could someone explain me what "Hermite Data" is? Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485908/basic-dual-contouring-theory) which says the important steps are described in 2.2. Sadly I don't quite understand the meaning of it. Because nowhere I could find a description what the (minimizer of the) quadratic function of this equation means:

E[x] = ∑
i
(ni
·(x− pi
))2

I don't know what to "input" in this function nor what it "outputs". Also they are talking about "cubes" but as far as I know a set of Voxels is just a quantity of data(0 or 1) and far as I have understand Dual Contouring takes those Voxels and turns them into a mesh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that context Hermite data is:

- Per each vertex:
- Sign (inside or outside of material) or material index
- Per each edge:
- Intersection point of edge and surface (can be stored as single float)
- Surface normal at intersection point

There is good explanation at https://web.archive.org/web/20160305101254/https://upvoid.com/devblog/2013/05/terrain-engine-part-1-dual-contouring/ and in paper https://web.archive.org/web/20170713094715if_/http://www.frankpetterson.com/publications/dualcontour/dualcontour.pdf

Comment: This gave me a good understanding of what Hermite Data is and how Dual Contouring works, thanks for you answer, even though I posted this question quite a while ago. I might actually try to do a implementation of this.

Comment: @CLOVIS Changed to archived version.